# subir imagen con laravel 5.7 y ajax

Tags: jquery, laravel

Hace varios dias estoy estancado tratando de subir imagenes pero no me funciona lo estraño es que el resto de los campos del formulario si lo hacen pero el de imagen es como si simplemente no estubiera ya me he leido un monton de manuales y revisado el codigo pero no logro encontrar el error me payudaria mucho que al menos me diaran alguna sugerencia para saber donde esta el problema

Esta es la migracion

```
    Schema::create('tours', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('description');
        $table->string('photo')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Este es el form que uso dentro de un modal:

```
    {!! Form::model($model, [

    'route' => $model->exists ? ['tours.update',app()->getlocale(), $model->id] : ['tours.store', app()->getlocale()],
    'method' => $model->exists ? 'PUT' : 'POST',
    'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']) !!}    

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="" class="control-label">Name</label>
        {!! Form::text('name', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'name']) !!}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="" class="control-label">Description</label>
        {!! Form::text('description', null ,['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'description']) !!}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="" class="control-label">Foto</label>
        {!! Form::file('photo', null ,['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'photo']) !!}
    </div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

El controlador:

```
     public function store($locale, Request $request)
    {
         $this->validate($request,[
        'name'        => 'required|max:120',
        'description' => 'required|max:120'
        'photo'       => 'image|max:2048'
        ]); 
         $input = $request->all();
        $input ['photo'] = null;

        if ($request->hasFile('photo'))
        {
            $input ['photo'] = '/image'.str_slug($input['name'],'-').'.'.$request->photo->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $request->photo->move(public_path('/image'), $input['photo']);            
        }

        Tour::create($input);
        return response()->json(['success' => true]);
}
```

Y este es mi godigo ajax:

```
//SAVE / UPDATE
$('#modal-btn-save').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    var form = $('#modal-body form'),
    url = form.attr('action'),
    method = $('input[name=_method]').val() == undefined ? 'POST' : 'PUT';

    form.find('.help-block').remove();
    form.find('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');

    $.ajax({
        url : url,
        method : method,
        data : new FormData($('#modal form')[0]),
        contentType : false,
        proceessData : false,
        success: function (response){
            form.trigger('reset');
            $('#modal').modal('hide');
            $('#datatable').DataTable().ajax.reload();

            swal({
                type : 'success',
                title : 'Success!',
                text : 'Data has been saved!'
            });
        },
        error : function (xhr){
            var res = xhr.responseJSON;
            if ($.isEmptyObject(res) == false){
                $.each(res.errors, function (key, value){
                    $('#' + key)
                        .closest('.form-group')
                        .addClass('has-error')
                        .append('<span class="help-block"><strong>' + value + '</strong></span>')
                });
            }
        }
    })
});
```

muchas gracias por adelantado y disculpen mi ingnorancia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

prueba a mover la foto asi :

```
$request->file('photo')->move(public_path('/image'), $input['photo']);
```

Vale para lo que me comentas que te da un 419 , el problema está en el método del AJAX, para mandar un PUT con ajax tiene que realizar lo a través del metodo POST y mandando una variable llamada "_method" con el valor "PUT"

```
$ajax({
    method: POST,
    url: $(this).prop('action'),
    data: { testData: 'this is a test' , '_method':'PUT'},
    headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': token },
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        console.log(data);    // prints out the data
    }
});
```

Este problema se basa en que la mayoría de los navegadores dan sólo soporte a GET y POST. Llevamos mucho tiempo arrastrando este problema. Un saludo.

Comment: Muchas gracias pwron, funciono perfectamente. Ahora el problema es con el update, el server me devuelve un 419 y estoy revisando para ver porque

Comment: @Cgun2 los 419 suelen estar relacionados con los token de CSRF , asegurate de que estas enviando el token al update.

Comment: muchas grcias por lel tip voy a revisar pero el form  y el metodo de ajax son el mismo para el create y el update asi que a lo mejor tengo algun otro error porque el create me funciona de lo mejor

Comment: @Cgun2 te he editado la respuesta con tu nuevo comentario.

Comment: disculpa la demora, trate de la forma que me pusiste para el 419 y no me funciono de todas maneras muchas qracias